# android: register application to receive sms

Tags: android

how can I register my application so that when I receive a sms my app appears in dialog Complete action using. I have put in an intent code

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="sms"/>
</intent-filter>
```

but it's not working... should I use receiver? Note that the activity in which I've inserted this code is not main activity. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
<activity android:name=".SMSNewActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SMSMainListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 4):

Its not well documented in doc.

You can find info on
[AndDev](http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html)

Here are some extracts:

1. You must use following permission, include it in your AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

2. You must not declare an intent filter in your activity for the same but filter it in a receiver, include following your manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

3. Create a class that extends `android.content.IntentReceiver` and override the onReceiveIntent method of the class listen for action `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` not part of SDK

Here's some more code extract:

```
// @Override
public void onReceiveIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
            // if(message starts with SMStretcher recognize BYTE)
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            /* The SMS-Messages are 'hiding' within the extras of the Intent. */
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                /* Get all messages contained in the Intent*/
                SmsMessage[] messages =
                    Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);

                /* Feed the StringBuilder with all Messages found. */
                for (SmsMessage currentMessage: messages) {
                    sb.append("Received compressed SMSnFrom: ");
                    /* Sender-Number */
                    sb.append(currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
                    sb.append("n----Message----n");
                    /* Actual Message-Content */
                    sb.append(currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody());
                }
            }
            /* Logger Debug-Output */
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "[SMSApp] onReceiveIntent: " + sb);

            /* Show the Notification containing the Message. */
            Toast.makeText(context, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I can only use android.content.IntentSender, android.content.IntentFilter and android.content.Intent...

Comment: public class TestSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
            System.out.println("I got an sms");
       }
    }
} but still it's not working. I am notified only when I receive a message, but I want that my application to be in dialog Complete action using...

Comment: FYI, IntentReceiver was removed from the Android SDK and was replaced by BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: The page you linked doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

See this free chapter from the book *Beginning Android Application Development*, which show in details how to receive (and send) SMS's:

http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/creating-android-apps-send-and-receive-sms-messages-and-send-email

Answer (score 0):

You will need this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: SEND_SMS, READ_SMS, WRITE_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, BROADCAST_SMS