# ACTION Cannot be resolved - Android SMS Programming

Tags: android

I am following a tutorial regarding a certain SMS Android program, specifically SMS Parsing.

I had this particular error that i meet...

```
    Public class SMSTestActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {  
        public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                        Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                        SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length];
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the action to your class :

```
static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
```

Don't forget to add the following snippet to the manifest :

```
<uses-permission id="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<application>
    <receiver class="SMSTestActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:value="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Source : [android: register application to receive sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257045/android-register-application-to-receive-sms)